# Subscribing to menu events after finding a window and adding said menu

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I want to create a .dll to find a window, add a menu bar, and then respond when a menu item is selected. I can successfully find the window, add the menu system, but am completely lost when it comes to identifying if a menu selection has been triggered. Any insight is appreciated, I'm very green with the Win32 API.

```
bool testDLL()
{
    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"Sandbox");

    if (hWnd) {
        CreateAMenu(hWnd);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}


#define ID_NEW_ITEM        1001
#define ID_SAVE_ITEM       1002
#define ID_QUIT_ITEM       1003

void CreateAMenu(HWND hWnd)
{
    HMENU hMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();

    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_NEW_ITEM, L"New Record");
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_SAVE_ITEM, L"Save Record");
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_QUIT_ITEM, L"Quit");
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hSubMenu, L"File");

    SetMenu(hWnd, hMenu);
}
```

Comment: Menu commands are dispatched via [WM_COMMAND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-command) messages. To handle them you would need to either subclass the window or otherwise hook into the message pump. How to do that depends first of all on whether the window is owned by the same process that runs the dll or not.

Comment: When a menu item is selected, a `WM_COMMAND` message is sent to the `HWND` that owns the menu, containing the ID of the menu item that was selected. For what you are trying to do, you would have to hook the `HWND` to intercept that message, such as via `SetWindowLongPtr()`/`SetWindowSubclass()` if the DLL is running in the same thread as the `HWND`, or else via `SetWindowsHookEx()` otherwise.

Comment: Feel free let me know if you still have any concern about this issue.